# GET API works from web browser and postman but not from php CURL

Tags: php, api, curl, postman

I want to get data of the following API from PHP code:

https://www.onthehouse.com.au/odin/api/marketstats/markets/trends/SHEIDOW+PARK/sa/5158?propertyType=House&timePeriod=1

It works fine when I run it in the browser and postman.

Can someone please provide a PHP code snippet for this?

I am using the following code:

---

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl,[
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.onthehouse.com.au/odin/api/marketstats/markets/trends/SHEIDOW+PARK/sa/5158?propertyType=House&timePeriod=1',
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'whatever']);
$response = curl_exec($curl);

echo $response;
?>
```

---

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to get you started. Just does the basics and does work for your API.

```php
$request = curl_init();
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.onthehouse.com.au/odin/api/marketstats/markets/trends/SHEIDOW+PARK/sa/5158?propertyType=House&timePeriod=1');
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Accept: application/json', 'Content-Type: application/json']);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($request);
curl_close($request);
// output response
var_dump($response);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I really appreciate it.

However, it still doesn't display the API data when I copy-paste your code. Having it worked would save me heaps of time. Would really appreciate your further help to resolve this.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Strangely, it displayed the output once correctly which was great, but now it keeps redirecting me to a 404 page with a little output on the top of the 404 page saying "string(816) "

Comment: It works, its just that the API service you are using requires you to complete a captcha first. If you have some way around that then the code will work every time. You can test that the code works by changing the url to another API service.

Comment: Many thanks, am not really sure how to complete Captcha. It's a pity we were almost there. I guess I will just give up here. Do you know how to complete the captcha for this particular API? Thank you kindly,

Comment: Sorry, I don't. I would recommend you reach out to their support and ask them. Good luck.